# Replacing every nth comma in string output with "\n"

Tags: replacement, string-manipulation

[image]

Feels like a strange question to ask, but I basically have a string with sets within sets, and it seems like the simplest formatting solution to seeing the data without needing to import everything into table or column form would be to replace every 7th comma in the string with \n to indent a new line. Mind you, this is the 7th itself starting from a count of 1 - not the 8th following 7. So starting from a count of 1, incrementing by 1 per count of a comma, all commas corresponding to a value where 'order' mod 7 = 0 would be replaced in the string by "\n". Is this a weird or nonsensical way of doing it? If I wanted to anyway, how would I implement what command generally?

Input

```
ps = Prime@Range[5, 16];
divs = x /. Solve[4 + x <= # && 1 + # <= 2 x, Primes] & /@ ps;
sets = MapThread[Thread[{#1, #2}] &, {ps, divs}];
results = 
  Map[With[{p = #[[1]], 
      x = #[[2]]}, (((Binomial[Reverse[Range[((p + 1)/2), (p - 3)]], 
          Range[(p - 3) - ((p + 1)/2) + 1]])))/x] &, sets, {2}];

matches = 
 ReplaceList[
  Flatten[MapThread[Transpose[{##}] &, {sets, results}], 
   1], {___, {{p1_, d1_}, {pre1___, val1_, ___}}, ___, {{p2_, 
       d2_}, {pre2___, val2_, ___}}, ___} /; 
    d1 == d2 && val1 == val2 && Length@{pre1} < Length@{pre2} :> 
   With[{r1 = Length@{pre1} + 2, 
     r2 = Length@{pre2} + 2}, {d1, {p1, r1}, {p2, r2}, 
     val1, (r2 - (r1 + ((r2 - r1)/2)))}]]
```

Output

> ```
> {{13, {17, 4}, {23, 10}, 220/13, 3}, 
>  {17, {23, 6}, {29, 12}, 4368/17, 3}, 
>  {19, {23, 6}, {29, 12}, 4368/19, 3}, 
>  {23, {29, 6}, {41, 18}, 26334/23, 6}, 
>  {29, {41, 12}, {47, 18}, 21474180/29, 3}, 
>  {29, {41, 10}, {53, 22}, 493350, 6}, 
>  {31, {41, 12}, {47, 18}, 21474180/31, 3}, 
>  {31, {41, 10}, {53, 22}, 14307150/31, 6}, 
>  {37, {41, 12}, {47, 18}, 21474180/37, 3}, 
>  {37, {41, 10}, {53, 22}, 14307150/37, 6}, 
>  {29, {47, 14}, {53, 20}, 11978400, 3}, 
>  {31, {47, 14}, {53, 20}, 11205600, 3}, 
>  {37, {47, 14}, {53, 20}, 347373600/37, 3}, 
>  {41, {47, 14}, {53, 20}, 347373600/41, 3}, 
>  {43, {47, 14}, {53, 20}, 347373600/43, 3}}
> ```

Comment: Use `StringSplit` to break at commas, the `Partition` to partition into groups of 7 (read the doc on how not to drop the remaining elements not a multiple of 7), finally use StringRiffle to assemble the subgroups, then the whole list, with appropriate separators at each level.  Also looks up `@@@`, `Apply` and pure functions, to write the same thing more compactly.

Comment: Please supply sample string in/output. This will make understanding your question so much easier.

Comment: Want every 7th comma replaced with a \n to break into a new line instead of wrapping endlessly across the page

Comment: @TravisArlenMcCracken This sort of information should be edited into the main question instead of comments.  Use the edit link below the question and make sure to put any code in code blocks.  Formatting help is available by clicking the (?) button during editing.

Comment: @Szabolcs Okay I pasted the code it into the problem description, but some of the formatting and text like _ (underscore) was lost in translation somehow, and apparently part of it became bold (?); copying it over back into Mathematica makes it glitch up, so I attached a screenshot of it in the program itself so it's easy to sort out what's not right when you copy it over. Just need every the 7th comma replaced with \n

Comment: @TravisArlenMcCracken: As I've *already asked*  in your prior question comments *what is unsatisfactory* about `Column[matches]`? And please, *do not* post screen-shots when proper code insertion could be used - *read the help* for editing and how to do this...

Comment: @ciao Column[matches] isn't unsatisfactory per se, I'm just not having luck implementing it. I'm a complete novice to mathematica. I'd be fine with that I suppose if I could get it to work, though \n sounds simple enough.

Comment: @TravisArlenMcCracken: "Having trouble implementing it"? What does that mean? Simply enter `Column[matches]` and evaluate it - it gives each set on its own line - is that not what you're after?

Comment: @ciao Holy #@!& you're right, I just had to type it in! Here I was all going to the online guide for it and complicating things like an idiot hahah. Went to ( https://reference.wolfram.com/language/DatabaseLink/tutorial/ColumnStructure.html ). Thanks so much, this is all I needed. Ugh sorry to waste your time, I've all I need now!

Comment: @TravisArlenMcCracken Have you looked at the formatting help that I suggested?  You need to put it in a code block to keep code intact (and prevent all that bold and italic, etc.)  It's easier if you look at the help page than if we try to squeeze all that formatting info in a comment ...

Comment: And where are those strings you are talking about in the title?

Comment: "Holy #@!& you're right, I just had to type it in!" - it's a nice thing about *Mathematica*, you can just try things since you're free to do so. :)

Answer (score 1):

I am somewhat confused about the aim. Here is an interpretation. Starting with string:

```
string = "{{13,{17,4},{23,10},220/13,3},{17,{23,6},{29,12},4368/17,3},\
{19,{23,6},{29,12},4368/19,3},{23,{29,6},{41,18},26334/23,6},{29,{41,\
12},{47,18},21474180/29,3},{29,{41,10},{53,22},493350,6},{31,{41,12},{\
47,18},21474180/31,3},{31,{41,10},{53,22},14307150/31,6},{37,{41,12},{\
47,18},21474180/37,3},{37,{41,10},{53,22},14307150/37,6},{29,{47,14},{\
53,20},11978400,3},{31,{47,14},{53,20},11205600,3},{37,{47,14},{53,20}\
,347373600/37,3},{41,{47,14},{53,20},347373600/41,3},{43,{47,14},{53,\
20},347373600/43,3}}"
```

My interpretation of aim:

```
ch = Characters[string];
pos = Position[ch, ","]
res = StringReplace[
  StringJoin @@ 
   ReplacePart[ch, Thread[Flatten[Last /@ Partition[pos, 7]] -> "J"]],
   "J" -> "\n"]
```

yielding string formatted as:

```
{{13,{17,4},{23,10},220/13,3}
{17,{23,6},{29,12},4368/17,3}
{19,{23,6},{29,12},4368/19,3}
{23,{29,6},{41,18},26334/23,6}
{29,{41,12},{47,18},21474180/29,3}
{29,{41,10},{53,22},493350,6}
{31,{41,12},{47,18},21474180/31,3}
{31,{41,10},{53,22},14307150/31,6}
{37,{41,12},{47,18},21474180/37,3}
{37,{41,10},{53,22},14307150/37,6}
{29,{47,14},{53,20},11978400,3}
{31,{47,14},{53,20},11205600,3}
{37,{47,14},{53,20},347373600/37,3}
{41,{47,14},{53,20},347373600/41,3}
{43,{47,14},{53,20},347373600/43,3}}
```